# Right way to define ManyToMany relationship on this model

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.3

I have this database model with a many-to-many relationship and of course that add a new table. This is the definition of the schema:

[image]

I need some help defining this part on `StockDetail` entity since it's a bit complex and I read [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-manytomany) and I'm more lost that I was before. The relationship isn't bidirectional since I'll get images trough `ProductDetail` objects, any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive it would look like this

```
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Acme\MediaBundle\Entity\Media")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="stock_detail_has_media",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="stock_detail", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="media", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)})
```

It is a one to many unidirectional relationship with join table as outlined at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-unidirectional-with-join-table